# JPA - Unique Value in multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, jpa

I need to ensure that the values of a column are not only unique within the column itself but also in a column of a different table which are independent (no joins).

Example:

Table A  
ID | Name 
1  | Peter 
2  | Manfred

Table B 
ID | Name 
 1 | Carl 
 2 | Richard

It should not be possible to add a new row to Table A with the Name "Richard" cause it already exists in Table B.

Is there a way to do that with constrains or do i have to build a validator?
I just found ways to ensure that with annotations within the same table.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like a very strange DB design

Comment: May be you can restrict in code level . I dont think you do with DB level . without any dependent.

Comment: This is a bit of a contradiction! If `Name` in `Table A` and `Table B` must be different, these tables are **not independent** - or should at least not be. If you can, you might want to rethink your DB design...

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `@EntityListeners` on both tables and in `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` write the logic which will check uniqueness.